# Grabbing the page number in the controller in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

How do I grab the page number in the controller of my php code and also set it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current page number will be in the Controller `params`.

Try debugging it to view its contents, or using the [DebugKit](http://github.com/cakephp/debug_kit):

```
// Within your controller action:
debug($this->request->params);
```

Comment: yeah i am looking in there with this print_r($this->request->params) but don't see page, but $this->paginator->current outputs 1. Where is the 1?

Comment: I found it: $this->request->params['named']['page'];

Answer (score 1):

Following gives you the page no in `cakephp 2`

```
$this->request->params['named']['page']
```